# Обособление приложения. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении *"Вместе со своим учителем, заслуженным деятелем искусств, профессором Александром Ивановым(,) они приняли участие в концертах в Новосибирске"* нужна запятая? Здесь главное слово - учитель, а приложение - заслуженный деятель искусств, профессор Александр Иванов?

Answer (score 3):

Да, приложение здесь *заслуженный деятель искусств профессор Александр Иванов.* Но только Ваша запятая посредине вроде не нужна. Могу ошибаться, но мне кажется, что "деятель" и "профессор" не однородные члены. А та запятая, что в скобках, — конечно, нужна.

> Вместе со своим учителем, заслуженным деятелем искусств профессором Александром Ивановым, они приняли участие в концертах в Новосибирске.

Мне кажется, что если я неправ, то есть если это однородные члены и запятая нужна, тогда лучше запятую заменить на "и" ("заслуженный деятель искусств и профессор"). Но, возможно, это также и дело вкуса и стиля.

Comment: Заслуженный деятель искусств и профессор - это вроде "стол большой и деревянный"

Comment: А-а, ну в таком случае я прав в том, что запятая не нужна. ;)

Comment: Да, Артём, вы правы как всегда.

Comment: Не иронизируйте, пожалуйста!))) Я тоже, как любой человек, ошибаюсь, и не редко. ;)